# Get the dock on the external sides of screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have this screen disposition. Currently the dock is on the bottom of my screens, it shows when I approach my mouse.

I'd like to get the dock on the external sides of my screens. Currently, I only can choose between left or right - but that means having one dock not comfortably usable on one of my screens.

Do you know if there is a solution for that ?

[image: Screens dispoition]